# Is there a MySQL setting to ignore "time" portion of datetime constant when applied to "DATE" column?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

> Disclaimer: this is needed for an old and ugly codebase that I'd much rather not touch.

- There is a table in the database that has a column (among many others) of `DATE` type.
- There is a query (auto generated by Torque criteria - don't ask) with `java.util.Date` parameter; Torque formats it as full datetime.

So, the query MySQL is getting is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
 WHERE my_date = '20091201105320'; // 2009-12-01 10:53:20
```

The problem is that on one server which has MySQL 5.0.27-standard it works just fine - as in returns all the records from `my_table` that have `my_date` set to '2009-12-01'. On another server which has MySQL 5.0.45 it does not work. The data is there - if I manually run the query after trimming the time portion out I get correct results back.

The question is:

Is there a setting somewhere, either in MySQL configuration file or in per-session variables (connection string) or somewhere else to force MySQL to ignore the time portion during string constant to date conversion?

I obviously can't use `DATE()` function without changing the codebase which I'd much rather not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I'm out of luck. From [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html):

Prior to MySQL 5.0.42, when `DATE` values are compared with `DATETIME` values, the time portion of the `DATETIME` value is ignored, or the comparison could be performed as a string compare. Starting from MySQL
5.0.42, a `DATE` value is coerced to the `DATETIME` type by adding the time portion as `'00:00:00'`.

Should anyone find themselves in a similar situation, the only workaround I found was to:

1. Reset time fields (hours / minutes / seconds) of the `java.util.Date` instance to zero.
2. Patch (and I do mean "patch" - there is no way to plug in your own adapter) `getDateString()` method of Torque's DB adapter for MySQL (`org.apache.torque.adapter.DBMM`) to check whether time fields of a date are zeroes and, if so, use "date-only" format.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than patching Torque

```
Criteria cr = new Criteria();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String fixedDate = dateFormat.format(date);
cr.add("my_date", (Object)("my_date = '" + fixedDate + "'"), Criteria.CUSTOM);
```